# Document Set in event receiver

Tags: document-library, event-receivers, document-set

I've a Document Library with a Content Type that inherit from **Document Set**.
I'd like to know how can i retrieve the metas when i upload or delete a file.
(`ItemUpdated` and `ItemDeleting`).

The `properties.listItem["meta"]` still always null when i delete a document in the event `ItemDeleting`

Thanks for your help